# Add "Select Category" when adding a document in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

When adding a new document and then showing its properties ("edit properties" from menu), i can not choose its category. It is done only after adding the aspect "Classifiable" from the document menu.

What i am looking for is: Category is shown by default in "edit properties" formm for every new document.

Please tell me how to do that, i am new to alfresco.

Some clues in [Alfresco website](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Classification_And_Categories) tells that we must customize model aspect.

Comment: Which Alfresco version are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Share and create an Inbound rule for a folder where you automatically want to add the aspect for new documents. (Perform Action -> Add Aspect Classifiable). Most likely you do not want to apply this to every document that is created in the entire repo. That said, if that is really what you want, stick the rule to the Repository folder and make it apply to subspaces as well.